# Nothing happens when I connect to my DB

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

can you explain me this ?

I've been working on some node.js stuff recently to learn it in order to build a DB interface. i've been able to execute this kind of `con.on()` a lot of time without troubles. but here, i'm quite confused.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var prompt = require('prompt');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "blabla",
    user: "bla",
    password: "bla",
    database: "blabla"
});

var schema_select = {
  properties: {
    select: {
      description: 'what you wanna select bro? :'

    },
    from: {
      description: 'from where bro ? :'
    },
    ask_where: {
      description: 'do you wanna add where ? Y/N :'
    },
    where: {
      description: 'say where then :',
      ask: function() {
        // only ask for WHERE option if user answered Y to ask_where question
        return prompt.history('ask_where').value == 'Y';
      }
    }
  }
};

con.on('error', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("[mysql error]",err);
    console.log("Connected!");

    prompt.get(schema_select, function (err, result) {
        //
        // Log the results.
        //
        console.log('Command-line input received:');
        var sql_request_where = '';
        if (result.ask_where == 'Y'){
            sql_request_where = 'WHERE ' + result.where;
        }
        var sql_request = 'SELECT ' + result.select + ' FROM ' + result.from;
        con.query(sql_request, function (err, req_result) {
            console.log(req_result);
            console.log("[mysql error]",err);
        })
    });
});
```

when I execute this code on console, it just basicaly do nothing, no error, no logs, nothing.
when i try to add some random `console.log('blabla')` outside the `con.on()` call it works, but it seems like i dont even entry `con.on()`...

```
C:\Users\flami\Desktop>node first.js

C:\Users\flami\Desktop>
```

thank you!

Comment: your `.on` only responds to an error, because it says `con.on('error', ..... )`, which means that `on error, do something`. Since there is no error, it won't do anything. maybe look up the documentation and see which event you have to handle for `on connect`. I assume it is `con.on('connect'` or `con.on('connection'`

Comment: sorry for this, am I cursing at you ?

Comment: @mitoufle assuming that `*$ù%ù` was a _"beep"_ word then the title of your question was inappropriate.

Comment: Ok my bad, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the package readme (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) you have to do `con.connect()`

`con.connect(callback)` takes a callback: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections

Answer (score 0):

your con.on only handles an error. As it succeeds (triggering a on('connect')) you do not handle it, thus the program considers everything is done; and quits;